# Convert from int to Integer and sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-stream

I am trying to convert from int to List Integer in order to apply the stream method to sort them, however it states that there's no suitable method. Is it possible to do it this way?

```
    public class Testsorting 
{
    public static int [] prize = {5,2,3,7,1,5,9,0,2};

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(prize).
                boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list);

        List <Integer> sortedList = Arrays.stream(list) //error occured on this line
                                           .sorted()
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Please make an effort to figure out the name of the language you're writing code in.

Comment: Use `list.stream().X`

Comment: I really don't understand down votes to this question. Decent question with clearly highlighted problem, and score -2 when writing this comment.

Comment: Why this detour? `Arrays.stream(prize)` produces a stream already. So you can do a single `List<Integer> sortedList = Arrays.stream(prize).sorted().boxed().collect( Collectors.toList());` Note that doing `sorted()` before `boxed()` will make sorting to the natural order more efficient. Only when needing a custom comparator, you’d need `.boxed() .sorted(comparator)`…

Comment: @Tinki perhaps, tagging a Java question with JavaScript led to the downvotes…

Comment: @Holger I don't get this reasoning. Selecting one wrong tag resulted with score -2 and really unpleasant comment from the editor? In my opinion border was crossed here.

Comment: @Tinki you would have to ask the people who downvoted. Unfortunately, it’s a common pattern that voters do not come back to a) retract the vote if the reason is no longer present or b) respond to comments asking for the reasons. I just speculated about the downvoter’s reasoning, I did not say that it was justified. But in the end, it’s not worth thinking about it too much. The OP still got a plus at the end of the day and the editor’s comment is not too harsh. Now, it’s the OP’s turn to accept an answer that solved the problem or tell us what’s still missing…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Arrays.stream(list)` to `list.stream()`

```
public class Main {
    public static int [] prize = {5,2,3,7,1,5,9,0,2};

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(prize).
                boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list);

        List <Integer> sortedList = list.stream() //error gone on this line
                                           .sorted()
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(sortedList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do below to achieve this in one line.

```
Arrays.stream(prize).sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
Arrays.stream(prize).boxed().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`.stream` converts to `IntStream` that supports `.sorted` method ootb but you can not collect `IntStream` directly into list like `Collectors.toList()` because this is supported in `Stream` class therefore we can use `.boxed` method to convert `IntStream` to `Stream` and you can then use shortcut `Collectors.toList` directly.

If you don't want to covert from IntStream to Stream by calling `boxed` explicitly you can use directly

```
Arrays.stream(prize).sorted().collect(ArrayList::new,ArrayList::add,ArrayList::addAll);
```

It will also give the same result.

Comment: The boxing conversion still happens in the last variant, it just has been moved to the `ArrayList::add` function, which requires an object argument. So the last variant just has longer source code than the variants using `boxed()`, without any advantage.